# Is visual model selection really faster than using mouse?

Tags: cut-copy-paste

I am interested in finding the faster way to edit.

My monitor is rotated 90 degrees vertically. When I code, I can see more lines than a typical monitor.

I found that using mouse to select is faster than:

1. Moving to the start of the copy region
2. Press <kbd>v</kbd>
3. Move the cursor to the end of the copy region
4. Press <kbd>y</kbd>
5. Jump to the paste position
6. Press <kbd>p</kbd>/<kbd>P</kbd>

This is obviously slower than using mouse. Am I missing something here? Can anyone share some insight?

Comment: This seems like a "primarily opinion-based" question, but anyway `v10w`, `v/`, `v10j`, `vip`, `vi{` etc, etc, are probably faster than using the mouse.

Comment: Also, [`gv`](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/visual.txt.html#gv) handily beats reselecting anything with the mouse.

Comment: You should really check this question: [Your problem with Vim is that you don't grok vi](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1218390/what-is-your-most-productive-shortcut-with-vim/1220118#1220118)

Answer (score 6):

You are missing the main point here, keyboard based editing tools are supposed to be faster because you don't have to change your hand position every once in a while.

Secondly, seeing how you visually select, you are only starting to use vim. There are much more useful ways of visual selection. The last thing I learnt was this `vaB`, which visually selects a block of code. In c/c++/java that means I can select a method with only 3 key presses; I don't even have to know where it started or ended. Stay with it, it'll change your editing style and make your life easier. But you have to stay with it.

And to bluntly answer your question, you're missing *everything useful*. Think about it. You're doing what you were doing with mouse, but now with keyboard. That's not very different at all. You'll need to learn (if you haven't already) about text objects and command line uses and much more.

Answer (score 0):

The main thing I like about vi is not having to move my hands from the keyboard. Even going to the arrow keys seems like a hassle to me. So switching my arm from keyboard to mouse seems like it'd be more exhausting.

Now regarding if it's faster or not. I guess it depends if there's an easy way to jump to the copy and paste positions but even if it's slow worst case scenario it won't be much slower.

Also sometimes it's much easier to copy/paste without the mouse. Let's say you want to replace the contents of brackets that stretch on multiple lines and are also surrounded by brackets ie: ({{(             )}}). Copy/pasting with the mouse would be much more of a hassle than doing it with the keys.

Even if you're not copying/replacing something that's in some easily selectable object (brackets, tags, close to some rare symbol) using relative number numbers + movement I feel it's still pretty fast and convenient.

I also have https://vimawesome.com/plugin/vim-multiple-cursors which is pretty helpful when I want replace a few occurrences of the same text but not all of them and I wouldn't be able to do that using the mouse.

Also you don't need to be in visual mode to yank.